Isekaied male finds a farmhouse. People come needing a place to stay and think he's a priest or running an orphanage
The main character was isekaied. He finds a house with a farm, and lives in it for a while. Later, on a rainy night or something, stranded people from another country come to him wanting a place to stay, thinking he's priest or running an orphanage.
I definitely read it online. There was magic. His hair was black, I think. I remember it being wholesome. I believe that he was good at farming, possibly due to a system.

When did you read this? Was it online? Do you remember how he was transported to the other world? Did he die? Was he addressed by a deity? Is there magic in this world? Does he have a system interface? Does he have a particular skill/talent? What color was his hair? Does the work have any significant nudity or violence?

It was defiantly online. There was magic, his hair was black I think. I remember it being wholesome. I believe that he was good at farming, possibly being due to a system.

You can [edit] those details in.

Might have been alluded to in https://www.reddit.com/r/manga/comments/11504xf/find_manga_in_which_mc_isekai_to_a_forest/. I've asked if they know the name.

he finds an abandoned church and cleans it up. then some orphan girls show up? and then later people think that he is the priest. did their house burn down or something?
i think even later than that, other people know that hes not the priest. sorry, i dont know the name of the manga though. but it is 100% black and white japanese manga isekai.

it feels really close to Tensei Kenja wa Musume to Kurasu . there is also "I Opened an Orphanage in Another World, But For Some Reason No One Wants to Leave." . it feels like theres another manga where the mc is more normal? and just finds a farmhouse , not given one by god and chased into it.

there is also "A B-Grade Adventurer With a Bad Guy Face Becomes a Daddy to the Protagonist and His Childhood Friends" but its not what you are looking for.

still looking, i found "Teihen Ossan, Cheat Kokusei de Isekai Rakuraku Life" but he hasnt found any abandoned houses so its not the right answer either.

This is Tensei Kenja wa Musume to Kurasu (The Reincarnated Sage Lives With His Daughters).

Meet Kento Oonari, salaryman in hell. Overworked by his bosses, his
head surely whirled. He dies, but meets up with a god called Raidel
who tells him that he'll be sent to a new world.
Kento is fairly cautious - he's read this before. And so, to the god,
he begs for one thing: "I just want to live a slow life, nothing more.
Just give me a house and a skill for farming."
So Kento is sent to a medieval age to live a nice, slow life. But what
a surprise! The god gave him the powers of a Great Sage! And Kento
used magic in front of commoner eyes!

Chapter 1.2 (page 6); The main character finds a church abandoned and lives there. Then other children show up and he cultivates a garden and takes care of them.



I've taken the liberty of adding in some links and images.
